# Undefined Reference Error to' base_rec::showme()'

Tags: c++, undefined-reference

So I'm doing a debug assignment for class. We are not allowed to make any serious code changes. My code is:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>


class base_rec
{public:
  base_rec (std::string contentstr):str(contentstr){};
  void showme();
  std::string str;};

class u_rec:public base_rec
{public:
  u_rec():base_rec("undergraduate records"){};
  void showme()
  {std::cout<<"showme() function of u_rec class\t" <<str<<std::endl;};};


class g_rec:public base_rec
{public:
  g_rec():base_rec("graduate records"){};
  void showme()
  {std::cout << "showme() function of a g_rec class\t"<<str<<std::endl;};};



  int main()
  { base_rec *brp[2];
    brp[1] = new u_rec;
    brp[2] = new g_rec;

    for (int i=0;i<1;i++)
      {brp[i]->showme ();}

    return 0;
}
```

however, whenever I try to compile it, I get the error message:

> /tmp/ccFm7Xvz.o: In function `main':
>   quiz2.cpp:(.text+0x54): undefined reference to`base_rec::showme()'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I'm not entirely sure what the problem is here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly:

```
brp[2] = new g_rec;
```

will be out of range since array index starting from `0`

secondly:

`showme` is  has no definition inside `base_rec`. If you really want to call derived class methods, you need to declare it as virtual.

Thirdly, you have several syntax errors in your code:

```
 u_rec():base_rec("undergraduate records"){}; //redundant ;
 void showme()
 {std::cout<<"showme() function of u_rec class\t" <<str<<std::endl;};
                                                     //redundant ; again
 //You can find several others.
```

You can do something like the following:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>


class base_rec
{
  public:
     base_rec (std::string contentstr):str(contentstr){}
     void showme(){ std::cout << "base class showme";}
     std::string str;
};

class u_rec: public base_rec
{
public:
    u_rec():base_rec("undergraduate records"){}
    void showme()
   {
      std::cout<<"showme() function of u_rec class\t" <<str<<std::endl;
   }
};


class g_rec:public base_rec
{
  public:
   g_rec():base_rec("graduate records"){};
     void showme()
     {
        std::cout << "showme() function of a g_rec class\t"<<str<<std::endl;
     }
};



int main()
{ 
    base_rec *brp[2];
    brp[0] = new u_rec;
    brp[1] = new g_rec;  //index starting from 0

   for (int i=0;i<1;i++)
   {
      brp[i]->showme ();
   }

   return 0;
}
```

If you really want to see how polymorphism works, you need to declare `showme` as `virtual` in the `base_rec` class. Then when you call it through base class pointers, it will show you polymorphism behavior. For example:

```
 class base_rec
 {
  public:
     base_rec (std::string contentstr):str(contentstr){}
     virtual void showme(){ std::cout << "base class showme";}
     std::string str;
 };
```